# Dynkin diagrams from Langlands's "Euler Products"

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I would like to reproduce the list of Dynkin diagrams at the end of Langlands's collection of lectures *[Euler Products](http://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/ep-ps.pdf)*. This list starts on p. 35.

[image]

I am using Benjamin McKay's Dynkin diagrams package. I've done several, but can't seem to be able to do (v), (ix), (xi), (xiii), (xxi), (xxvi), and all of the following. Would anyone know what I've missed?

For example, I can't find a way to put double edges between the first two nodes of a straight line of nodes, and nowhere else.

Item (iv) is easy enough. Ignoring the line that gives $r$, $a_1$ and $\lambda_1$, I have

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}  
\dynkin[edgeLength=1,arrows=false]{B}{oo.ooo};
\dynkinLabelRoot*{1}{2}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{2}{2}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{3}{2}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{4}{2}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{5}{1}
\dynkinLabelRoot{1}{\alpha_1}
\dynkinLabelRoot{2}{\alpha_2}
\dynkinLabelRoot{3}{\alpha_{n-1}}
\dynkinLabelRoot{4}{\alpha_n}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

One draws the diagram by specifying its name according to the [documentation](http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/dynkin-diagrams/dynkin-diagrams.pdf). There doesn't seem to be a diagram in the documentation that corresponds to (v) and other examples in Langlands's list. Is there another way of generating them that I've missed?

Comment: I just posted an answer, the trick of using `[xscale=-1]` will also work with the syntax you have chosen. But this is the reason why people want to see an MWE, how else would they know which route you have chosen?

Comment: A good point. I assumed that the question was high-level enough to not need an MWE, but judging by how this turned out, I could have helped out. I'll be more careful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Here is how you can get (v) from (iv) via `xscale=-1`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{(v)}

\begin{tikzpicture}  
\dynkin[edgeLength=1,xscale=-1]{B}{oo.ooo};
\dynkinLabelRoot*{1}{2}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{2}{2}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{3}{2}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{4}{2}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{5}{1}
\dynkinLabelRoot{1}{\alpha_n}
\dynkinLabelRoot{2}{\alpha_{n-1}}
\dynkinLabelRoot{3}{\alpha_2}
\dynkinLabelRoot{4}{\alpha_1}
\end{tikzpicture}

\paragraph{(ix)}

\begin{tikzpicture}  
\dynkin[edgeLength=1]{D}{oo.ooo};
\dynkinLabelRoot*{1}{1}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{2}{1}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{3}{1}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{4}{1}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{5}{1}
\dynkinLabelRoot{1}{\alpha_1}
\dynkinLabelRoot{2}{\alpha_{2}}
\dynkinLabelRoot{3}{\alpha_{n-1}}
\dynkinLabelRoot{5}{\alpha_n}
\end{tikzpicture}

\paragraph{(xi)}

\begin{tikzpicture}  
\dynkin[edgeLength=1,xscale=-1]{E}{ooooooo};
\dynkinLabelRoot*{1}{1}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{2}{1}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{3}{1}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{4}{1}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{5}{1}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{6}{1}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{7}{1}
\dynkinLabelRoot{1}{\alpha_6}
\dynkinLabelRoot{3}{\alpha_5}
\dynkinLabelRoot{4}{\alpha_4}
\dynkinLabelRoot{5}{\alpha_3}
\dynkinLabelRoot{6}{\alpha_2}
\dynkinLabelRoot{7}{\alpha_1}
\end{tikzpicture}

\paragraph{(xiii)}

\begin{tikzpicture}  
\dynkin[edgeLength=1,xscale=-1]{E}{oooooooo};
\dynkinLabelRoot*{1}{1}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{2}{1}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{3}{1}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{4}{1}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{5}{1}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{6}{1}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{7}{1}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{8}{1}
\dynkinLabelRoot{1}{\alpha_7}
\dynkinLabelRoot{3}{\alpha_6}
\dynkinLabelRoot{4}{\alpha_5}
\dynkinLabelRoot{5}{\alpha_4}
\dynkinLabelRoot{6}{\alpha_3}
\dynkinLabelRoot{7}{\alpha_2}
\dynkinLabelRoot{8}{\alpha_1}
\end{tikzpicture}

\paragraph{(xxi)}

\begin{tikzpicture}  
\dynkin[edgeLength=1,xscale=-1]{B}{ooo};
\dynkinLabelRoot*{1}{2}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{2}{2}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{3}{1}
\dynkinLabelRoot{1}{\alpha_3}
\dynkinLabelRoot{2}{\alpha_2}
\dynkinLabelRoot{3}{\alpha_1}
\end{tikzpicture}

\paragraph{(xiii)}

\begin{tikzpicture}  
\dynkin[edgeLength=1]{D}{oo.oooo};
\dynkinLabelRoot*{1}{1}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{2}{1}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{3}{1}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{4}{1}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{5}{1}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{6}{1}
\dynkinLabelRoot{1}{\alpha_1}
\dynkinLabelRoot{2}{\alpha_{2}}
\dynkinLabelRoot{3}{\alpha_{n-3}}
\dynkinLabelRoot{4}{\alpha_{n-2}}
\dynkinLabelRoot{5}{\alpha_{n-1}}
\dynkinLabelRoot{6}{\alpha_n}
\end{tikzpicture}

\paragraph{(xxvi)}

\begin{tikzpicture}  
\dynkin[edgeLength=1,xscale=-1]{E}{oooooooo};
\dynkinLabelRoot*{1}{1}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{2}{1}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{3}{1}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{4}{1}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{5}{1}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{6}{1}
\dynkinLabelRoot*{7}{1}
\dynkinLabelRoot{1}{\alpha_7}
\dynkinLabelRoot{3}{\alpha_6}
\dynkinLabelRoot{4}{\alpha_5}
\dynkinLabelRoot{5}{\alpha_4}
\dynkinLabelRoot{6}{\alpha_3}
\dynkinLabelRoot{7}{\alpha_2}
\dynkinLabelRoot{8}{\alpha_1}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

All the other diagrams are completely analogous, you need just to remember that the labeling gets reversed, i.e. root 1 will be on the right. The output is not optimal since labels are placed on top of some other elements (lined). See the code below for how to fix that.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**(prior to the OP's MWE, perhaps useful for others): All these diagrams are straightforward with that package.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \dynkin[name=reverseCn,xscale=-2,yscale=2,arrows=false]{C}{}
 \foreach \X in {1,...,5}
 {\node[above=0pt of reverseCn root \X]{\ifnum\X=5
 1
 \else
 2
 \fi};}
 \node[below=0pt of reverseCn root 1]{$\alpha_{n}$};
 \node[below=0pt of reverseCn root 2]{$\alpha_{n-1}$};
 \node[below=0pt of reverseCn root 3]{$\alpha_{2}$};
 \node[below=0pt of reverseCn root 4]{$\alpha_{1}$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \dynkin[name=Dn,scale=2]{D}{}
 \foreach \X in {1,...,6}
 {\node[above=0pt of Dn root \X]{1};}
 \foreach \X in {1,2}
 {\node[below=0pt of Dn root \X]{$\alpha_\X$};}
 \node[below=0pt of Dn root 3]{$\alpha_{n-2}$};
 \node (anm1) at([yshift=-3pt]Dn root 3|-Dn root 6){$\alpha_{n-1}$};
 \draw[-latex] (anm1) to[out=20,in=-110] (Dn root 4);
 \node[below=0pt of Dn root 6]{$\alpha_{n}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \dynkin[name=reverseE8,xscale=-2,yscale=2,ordering=Dynkin]{E}{8}
 \foreach \X in {1,...,8}
 {\node[above=0pt of reverseE8 root \X]{1};}
 \foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using int(8-\X)]in {1,...,7}
 {\node[below=0pt of reverseE8 root \X]{$\alpha_\Y$};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \dynkin[name=reverseB3,xscale=-2,yscale=2,ordering=Dynkin,arrows=false]{B}{3}
 \foreach \X in {1,...,3}
 {\node[above=0pt of reverseB3 root \X]{1};}
 \foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using int(4-\X)]in {1,...,3}
 {\node[below=0pt of reverseB3 root \X]{$\alpha_\Y$};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I am going to bed now, and so I'll review it tomorrow. Still, I'm greatly relieved! Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks again! I've accepted the answer. It's not relevant, but I did need an `arrows=false` as in your second example. I've added it. Further, your (xxvi) should be (xiii) and your (xiii) should probably be (xxiii). (The diagram in the pdf is probably wrong. The published version matches your diagram with the two angled nodes flipped. I understand now how to do the diagrams, but think that you like having answers as correct in as many ways as possible, and so I thought I'd point it out. If these details don't bother you, no worry! You've answered the question, and I am extremely grateful!)

Comment: @AnthonyPulido Thanks! Yes, there are many typos in the linked pdf. But this is not a maths site, only TeX. I was using `arrows=false` in my original answer, which IMHO also produces a nicer output (except in the third diagram, where I messed up;-). I'd wish that  `\dynkinLabelRoot` places the labels in such a way that they do not collide with the lines between the roots/nodes.

Comment: I agree. I am just listing both labels in the side that doesn't collide with the diagram, like {{1, \alpha_n}}, etc., which seems OK for now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

The latest version (3.141) of the `dynkin-diagrams` package does a better job of keeping root labels out of the way of the edges. Langlands's table is included in the package documentation, but here it is in a complete code sample:

[image: Langlands's table page 1][image: Langlands's table page 2]

[image: Langlands's table page 3]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}
\usepackage{longtable}
\tikzset{/Dynkin diagram,ordering=Dynkin,label macro/.code={\alpha_{#1}}}
\newcounter{EPNo}
\setcounter{EPNo}{0}
\NewDocumentCommand\EP{smmmm}%
{%
\stepcounter{EPNo}\roman{EPNo}. &
\def\eL{.6cm}
\IfStrEqCase{#2}%
{%
{D}{\gdef\eL{1cm}}%
{E}{\gdef\eL{.75cm}}%
{F}{\gdef\eL{.35cm}}%
{G}{\gdef\eL{.35cm}}%
}%
\tikzset{/Dynkin diagram,edge length=\eL}
\IfBooleanTF{#1}%
{\dynkin[backwards,labels*={#4},labels={#5}]{#2}{#3}}
{\dynkin[labels*={#4},labels={#5}]{#2}{#3}}
\\
}%
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{rl}
\caption{Dynkin diagrams from Robert P. Langlands, \emph{Euler products}, Yale University Press, New Haven, Conn.-London, 1971, A James K. Whittemore Lecture in Mathematics given at Yale University, 1967, Yale Mathematical Monographs, 1. MR 0419366}
\\
\endfirsthead
\caption{\dots continued}\\
\endhead
\multicolumn{2}{c}{continued \dots}\\
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
\EP{A}{***.**}{1,1,1,1,1}{,1,2,n-1,n}
\EP{A}{***.**}{1,1,1,1,1}{1,2,n-1,n}
\EP{A}{**.***.*}{1,1,1,1,1,1}{1,2,m-1,,m,n}
\EP{B}{**.***}{2,2,2,2,1}{1,2,n-1,n}
\EP*{B}{***.**}{2,2,2,2,1}{n,n-1,2,1,}
\EP{C}{**.***}{1,1,1,1,2}{1,2,n-1,}
\EP*{C}{***.**}{1,1,1,1,2}{n,n-1,2,1,}
\EP{D}{**.****}{1,1,1,1,1,1}{1,2,n-2,n-1,n}
\EP{D}{**.****}{1,1,1,1,1,1}{1,2,n-2,n-1,n}
\EP{E}{6}{1,1,1,1,1,1}{1,...,5}
\EP*{E}{7}{1,1,1,1,1,1,1}{6,...,1}
\EP{E}{7}{1,1,1,1,1,1,1}{1,...,6}
\EP*{E}{8}{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}{7,...,1}
\EP{E}{8}{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}{1,...,7}
\EP{G}{2}{1,3}{,1}
\EP{G}{2}{1,3}{1}
\EP{B}{**.*.**}{2,2,2,2,1}{,1,2,n-1,n}
\EP{F}{4}{1,1,2,2}{,3,2,1}
\EP{C}{3}{1,1,2}{,2,1}
\EP{C}{**.***}{1,1,1,1,2}{,1,n-2,n-1,n}
\EP*{B}{3}{2,2,1}{1,2}
\EP{F}{4}{1,1,2,2}{1,2,3}
\EP{D}{**.****}{1,1,1,1,1,1}{1,2,n-2,n-2,n,n}
\EP{E}{6}{1,1,1,1,1,1}{1,2,3,4,,5}
\EP{E}{6}{1,1,1,1,1,1}{1,2,3,5,,4}
\EP*{E}{7}{1,1,1,1,1,1,1}{,5,...,1,6}
\EP*{E}{7}{1,1,1,1,1,1,1}{,6,4,3,2,1,5}
\EP*{E}{8}{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}{,6,...,1,7}
\EP*{E}{8}{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}{,7,5,4,3,2,1,6}
\EP*{E}{7}{1,1,1,1,1,1,1}{5,...,1,,6}
\EP*{E}{7}{1,1,1,1,1,1,1}{1,...,5,,6}
\EP*{E}{8}{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}{6,...,1,,7}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll mention your comments to Langlands. I'm sure he'll be glad for them.